# My heroku database got detached. How can i recover my heroku hobby dev postgres database?

Tags: database, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli, recover

i am facing an issue from heroku that shows **"Heroku marked free databases for deletion"**. my database is detached by heroku.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIrcj.png)

i want to recover my database. when i tried to raise a ticket through heroku support, it shows **"Technical support for Free applications is provided by the online community"**. but there is no solution available for my issue. i don't know how to recover. anyone please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5L9y.png)

This is my first question on stackoverflow. if i did not provided more details regarding my issue, i am extremely sorry

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [we literally cannot help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577). One way or another, you need to contact Heroku support. (Note that Heroku no longer offers free services at all.)

Answer (score 2):

Your database has been deleted from Heroku because Heroku removed the free plans.
So you need to create your database again (its no longer free).

- Go to the "Resources" tag on your_app's dashboard
- Select "Heroku Postgres" option in the Add-ons field.
- After selecting the plan (min $5/month), Click "Submit Order Form" button.
  Then, a new database will be created and connected to your app.

Then, you can configure the database using heroku cli commands. E.g.,
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
$ heroku run rake db:seed

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

Contact heroku support and [open a support ticket](https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new).

Apparently, according to this article, they can still recover detached databases for 10 days:

https://help.heroku.com/SPTSN5U6/can-i-recover-a-deprovisioned-production-non-hobby-mini-basic-heroku-postgres-database